# When using PhpStorm 10, how can I get the browser to recognize the 'input' name array?

Tags: php, html, forms, phpstorm

I'm a novice learning PHP and am stuck on a basic issue. It looks like a configuration issue. I reviewed stackoverflow, tutorials, and PhpStorm documentation, but was unable to find a simple answer.

I'm trying to get HTML form data to post a message upon submitting the form. There are two php files, the example.php has the php script, and the welcome.php file has the HTML with the php echo script. The HTML text information is returned, but Chrome throws an error notice, ***Notice: Undefined index: name in ... welcome.php on line 4***, related to the submitted name and email array.

PhpStorm gives me a warning on the example.php file, ***form input 
without associated label or form attribute***. My conclusion is that PhpStorm is not associating the two files.

I'm using PHP 7.0.0, with C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\htdocs

example.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <body>
    <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body> 
    Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: basic debugging: `var_dump($_POST)` and see what's arriving at the welcome script. maybe that's not really "name". it's "name+invisible chars".

Comment: When I debug I get the same error. I did not get any results with the var_dump.

Answer (score 3):

PhpStorm has nothing to do with the error.

If you just go to welcome.php page it will give an error because there is no $_POST submission. You can check if there is any submission first.

Welcome.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body> 
    Welcome <?php if(isset($_POST['name'])){ echo $_POST["name"]; }?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php if(isset($_POST['email'])) { echo $_POST["email"];} ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the above code. The error is gone, but the data in the submit fields does not display. FYI both if(isset) lines of code were missing the closing ).

Comment: @SteveSchinker thanks for correction. I just updated the answer with closing )s. Make sure inputs and post have the same names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm following a beginners tutorial. I tried a basic echo, nothing displayed in the browser. It looks like this is part of my initial problem. No errors, no problem with the code. That's why I thought this was a problem with PhpStorm.

learnphp.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Information Gathered
    <body>
    <?php
    echo "<p>Data processed</p>";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code above does not relate to my initial issue. The closing title tag was missing.

Answer (score 0):

This was a configuration issue. PhpStorm was defaulting to the PhpStorm port and not port 80.
PhpStorm wasn't properly configured to work with the server. I uninstalled wamp and installed xampp, that didn't fix the problem, but gave me more control.

In Settings, Build, Execution, Deployment:
Type: Local or mounted folder is required because my project is on my D: drive,     and server is on my C: drive
Mappings: Use this server as default button must be selected
Web path on server 'xampp': must be the project file folder